# Execute all environments in tox

Tags: tox

I have an envlist defined in the [tox] section:
[tox]
`envlist = cpySrc, py27-{AirSuspensionWakeup,AuxiliaryLightsControl}, py37-merge`

The issue is that in the ContinousIntegration they are expecting the execution of only one environment and there is no option to change it:
**tox -e test**
Is there any way to execute all my envlist even when command line option -e is specified?
Thanks

I can execute locally without "-e" but when I move it to the CI, tox is called specifying an environment.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, the problems are:

1. A CI system tailored to a very opinionated use of a particular tooling.
2. You not having a chance to leverage changes in the CI system.

Those smell like crappy workflow decisions, not a technical problem. Those are what you really need to solve.

---

You can add an additional testenv:test that will trigger the others like

```
[tox]
envlist = test,aaa,bbb

[testenv:test]
deps = tox
commands = tox -e aaa,bbb

[testenv:aaa]
commands = python -c 'print("aaa")'

[testenv:bbb]
commands = python -c 'print("bbb")'
```

But then again you may have a lot of trouble with different interpreter discoverability because `tox -e aaa,bbb` will already run in an isolated tox environment. So, good luck hacking that.